# Get image size already on DOM with jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With this code i can have the original size of the image:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = 'something.jpg';
```

and what if i have all images loaded on DOM already, how can i get the same info!?

Thanks ;-)

Comment: Why can't you just use `img.width + 'x' + img.height`, in case the image is loaded already.

Comment: Possible clone of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript ?

Comment: You could use jQuery `each` function - https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/LavhLt50/